# Why does this halt my perl application package 'not registered for warnings'

Tags: perl

I am working with an in house web gateway frame work in perl. And now I am trying to use Image::Magick::Thumbnail to create a thumbnail image.

But if I have this line

```
my ($thumb, $x, $y) = Image::Magick::Thumbnail::create($image, 50);
```

I get the following error.

```
package 'Image::Magick::Thumbnail' not registered for warnings
```

I have tracked this down to line 313 of warnings.pm

```
        Croaker("package '$category' not registered for warnings")
```

But I'm not sure why this halts my program any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use warnings::register;` creates a warnings category with the same name as the current package.

Image::Magick::Thumbnail checks if warnings of category `Image::Magick::Thumbnail` are enabled, but doesn't actually create such a category using `use warnings::register;`.

The line is there in the code, but it's commented out?! You could edit the module to uncomment that line to solve the problem. Including the following in your script should also do the trick:

```
{
   package Image::Magick::Thumbnail;
   use warnings::register;
}
```